# Auto generation of test cases allowed in karate dsl?

Tags: karate

looking for some record and play capability or auto generation of test cases in karate dsl automation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Karate supports converting Postman, HAR, cURL and OpenAPI / Swagger specs in the [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate) and [IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate) IDE plugins (premium upgrade).